# Setup.py file for bundling a Flask program with py2app

Tags: python, flask, py2app

I can't really find any documentation anywhere for using py2app with a Flask program. How should I set up the setup.py file?

[Here's the dependencies I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4qO5.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do (at least) TWO things to make a macOS app with flask via py2app:

- configure your `setup.py` properly
- reconfigure your `__init__.py`

The gotcha that will hit after you build the app for the first time via a good version of `setup.py` with a proper list of `packages` is an inability to serve your static content and templates (until you configure a list of `resources` in `setup.py` and reconfigure the app's `__init__.py`). You have to set the template folder and the static folder to somewhere that both `setup.py` and `__init__.py` can use.

But, before you get too excited, you should realize that you will have (significant) new problems with your new app: first, the application has no icon, no menu presence, and no way to give you feedback. You will need to "Force Quit" to exit it. It is probably more useful to run via the terminal:

`$ ./dist/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp`

But here is the **big** problem: you just hard-coded the path to the templates with an absolute path. If you move the app, then it will lose the ability to find its data:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
```

If you poke around a bit you will become tempted by the possibility that setting the templates path to something like `../../templates` would work. It won't. py2app and its magic will include a file in your flask paths where you need a directory: something like `python36.zip`.


You probably want more from your app in the end. But this is definitely a start: compiled. As you can see, I more or less stopped here. I was not desperate to have my scripts be an app, and it was looking like py2app and flask really did not want to play nicely together. There is probably a way to get something both compiled and truly portable, but I am not the person to answer that bit for you. Good luck!

---

sample `setup.py`

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet
Usage: python setup.py py2app
"""
APP = ['myapp.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'packages': ['flask', 'werkzeug', 'config', 'jinja2'],
    'resources': ['./server/templates', './server/static'],
    }
setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

---

modified `__init__.py`

```
myapp = Flask(__name__,
    template_folder='/path/to/dist/dir/dist/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/templates', 
    static_folder='/path/to/dist/dir/dist/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/static')
```